# Como manter os dados do form após submeter utilizando Codelgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sou iniciante com a utilização do Framework Codelgniter, tenho uma duvida como faço para manter os dados do meu formulários após submeter a página, estou criando um formulario com bastantes campos a ser preenchido, se o usuário deixar um campo em branco ou escrever de forma errada vai gerar uma msg de erro, eu queria que o usuario tivesse a opção de voltar no form e resgatar o que foi digitado.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'NOME', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[40]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('data_nasc', 'DATA DE NASCIMENTO', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('rg', 'RG', 'required|exact_length[9]|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpf', 'CPF', 'required|exact_length[11]|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sexo_pessoa', 'SEXO DO CLIENTE', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('rua', 'RUA', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[20]|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('numero', 'NUMERO', 'required|max_length[5]|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cep', 'CEP', 'required|exact_length[8]|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('estado', 'ESTADO', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cidade', 'CIDADE', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bairro', 'BAIRRO', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tel1', 'TELEFONE 1', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[11]|numeric');      
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_tel1', 'CATEGORIA DO TELEFONE 1', 'required|numeric');       
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome_animal', 'NOME DO ANIMAL', 'alpha|required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('categoria_animal', 'CATEGORIA DO ANIMAL', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('raca', 'RAÇA', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sexo_animal', 'SEXO DO ANIMAL', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cor', 'COR', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('porte', 'PORTE', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('data_nasc_animal', 'DATA DE NASCIMENTO DO ANIMAL', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        if(validation_errors()){
            die('<p> <a href="'.base_url('cadastro_cliente').'"> Clique aqui </a> para voltar</p>'.validation_errors());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa duas coisas para fazer os valores voltarem preenchidos num formulário que deu errado:

1°) Chamar de novo a `view` passando um `$data` com o valor destes campos que você passou por validação. 2°) Ter programado os campos do formulário com `value=` recebendo a função `set_data()`, que testa ou não se existe o valor, para quando o formulário está ou não zerado.

Se todos os campos vieram por POST, você monta rapidinho um `$data` pegando os valores do PHP `$_POST`. Se alguma variável não está no POST, você tem que adicionar na mão. Logo:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    if(validation_errors()){
        $data = $this->input->post();

        // Adiciona uma variável manualmente no $data
        $data['erros_do_form'] = validation_errors();

        // Usuário volta para o mesmo lugar onde estava
        $this->load->view('nome_da_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Na `view`, exiba para o usuário os erros acontecidos por meio da variável (array) `erros_do_form`.

Ainda na `view`, você precisa preparar os inputs para receber ou não valor, isto é, o mesmo form será chamado zerado ou com valores preenchidos. Exemplo para o campo nome_animal:

```
// null é o valor default aqui, mas poderia ser 'Lulu'
<input name="nome_animal" type="text" value="<?=set_value('nome_animal', null)?>">
```